# list() turns string to a list of integers instead of a list of strings

Tags: python, list, amazon-s3, url

I have used following to open a txt file in AWS s3 bucket

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://foldername.s3.amazonaws.com/mockfile.txt") as url:
    f = url.read()
    datalist= list(f)

    for i in range(len(datalist)):
        #datalist[i]=datalist[i].strip('\n')
        print(datalist[i])
```

This is the example of the data I am trying to read and preprocess

```
585978391360221184|Thu Apr 09 01:31:50 +0000 2015|Breast cancer risk test devised http://bbc.in/1CimpJF
585947808772960257|Wed Apr 08 23:30:18 +0000 2015|GP workload harming care - BMA poll http://bbc.in/1ChTBRv
585947807816650752|Wed Apr 08 23:30:18 +0000 2015|Short people's 'heart risk greater' http://bbc.in/1ChTANp
585866060991078401|Wed Apr 08 18:05:28 +0000 2015|New approach against HIV 'promising' http://bbc.in/1E6jAjt
585794106170839041|Wed Apr 08 13:19:33 +0000 2015|Coalition 'undermined NHS' - doctors http://bbc.in/1CnLwK7
585733482413891584|Wed Apr 08 09:18:39 +0000 2015|Review of case against NHS manager http://bbc.in/1Ffj6ci
```

However when I tried to make the read string into a list with the `datalist=list(f)` it turns the string into a list of integers like following

```
[53, 56, 53, 57, 55 ... ]
```

What I want is the `datalist` variable to hold the list of each data entry.
The following code works on a local file. I want something like it to work on this file.

```
f= open(url, "r", encoding="utf8")
data= list(f)

for l in range(len(data)):
    data[l]=data[l].strip('\n')
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Your `url.read()` returns a `bytes` object, not a `str` object. A `bytes` object is an iterable of ints in the range `[0, 255]` for each byte. 

You have to `decode` the `bytes` into a `str` object if you want to obtain a list of characters.

Comment: How can I open the file to get a file object like open(URL,"r") returns?

Comment: Like the previous comment already explains, you already have that, except you have `open(URL, "rb")`. To decode `f`, use `f.decode('utf-8')` (supposing that the encoding is indeed UTF-8).

Comment: ... And to split it into lines, you want `.splitlines()`. Looping over the decoded data directly will still produce one character per iteration.

Comment: Why not use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)? `df = pd.read_csv("https://foldername.s3.amazonaws.com/mockfile.txt", sep='|')`